# Windows 10 video changes system volume, not app volume, and missing from mixer

Tags: audio, windows-10-preview, volume-mixer

The Windows 10 Technical Preview Video app controls the system global volume setting from the app's main interface. It also doesn't have an entry in the volume mixer, while other programs do.

I am aware of and have already toggled allowing exclusive control to the audio device disabled / enabled with no consequence.

To be clear, audio in every other way functions normally - other programs have entries in the volume mixer, and the Video app plays audio.

[image: Screenshot of issue, note the missing entry for Video]

*Is there a way to get the Video app to have an entry in the volume mixer?*